# Git: how not to push branches to remote

Tags: git, git-branch

I have two remote git server, one is for *dev* where I push everything, the other should used just for the *milestones*.

What I want to do is committing and pushing everything to the dev server and pushging just the "master" branch on the milestones git.

Right now I have two folders locally (`dev\my_project` and `mile\myproject`) one tracked on the `dev` server and other tracked by the `milestone` one. When I have I milestone I copy-paste the source on the "milestone" folder then I commit and push.

more or less my flow is this

```
rem go on the folder tracked on dev
cd %userdir%\dev\myproject
pushd
rem move on master branch
git checkout master
rem copy all my sources on the milestone tracked folder 
rmdir /s /q %userdir%\mile\myproject\*
copy %userdir%\dev\sources\* %userdir%\mile\myproject
cd %userdir%\mile\myproject
git add *
git commit -m "milestone commit 123"
git push
```

I'd like not having to deal two local copies but being able to push only the master branch on the milestones git.

Comment: The `git push` command pushes *commits*, not branches. It then asks the server to set some branch(es) based on the names you tell it. So `git push origin br1 br2` pushes any new *commits* you have, that they don't, that they need to update their names `br1` and `br2` to match your names `br1` and `br2`. Use `git push <remote> <refspec>` to specify precisely which commits to send and what name on their side you want them to update.

Comment: If you run `git push` with no extra arguments, the default action is controlled by your `push.default` setting. The default for this `push.default` is `simple` in Git versions 1.9 and higher, but was `matching` in very old versions of Git. `matching` will pick up branch names you might not want sent, so consider upgrading your Git or setting your `push.default` to `simple` if your Git is new enough to have that setting.

Answer (score 0):

The branch concept exists for this. You can have many branches beside the branch master, and make the merge only change that you define as relevant.
Your development flow must be like this:

- master// with production code
- git checkout -b "branch-name"// create a new branch from master
- in this branch, you develop and add, commit and push the changes
- when finish, you make the merge with the master

If you have files that only will use in the local environment, you can add in [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file

Comment: My need is to avoid that commits made during developement will be uploaded to the milestone server. Working on branch is good, but once I push all the local commits go also on server

Comment: You can try to make the control using  `.gitignore` to add files that will have your changes ignored by git, and its don't will be uploaded to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your entire process, but I *think* you can get what you want by adding multiple remotes.

`git add remote <remote repo> milestone`

Let's assume `origin` is your dev server, and `milestone` is your milestone remote server.
Then, you'll need to specify the remote in your push command. Running the following would push all branches to your dev server (assuming  your push defaults in your .gitconfig are set up for it).

`git push origin'

And to push to the milestone server, you'd just want to add the branch to push (so you don't push everything):

`git push milestone master`

If you wanted to get more sophisticated, you could also add a server side git hook on the milestone server to disallow pushes from any branch other than master.